# Jave Maven project, how to add so many dependency jars in the third party's lib folder to the maven repository?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, repository

I am new to maven java projects. I have a maven java project, and a local repository for the dependency jars. I manually installed the jar by the command mvn deploy:.... whenever a dependency is needed.  However now, I have a SDK provided by a third party vendor, it has a lib folder with more than 30 jars inside, in this case, how do I install all these 30 jars into Maven repository manually, and I have to make up the group-id and artifacts for each individual jar, and run the mvn deploy command one by one.  Am I missing anything here? I thought Maven is supposed to make the project management easier. In this case, what are my options?

1. Install the jars in the lib to the repository one by one?
2. Convert my project back to regular java project, so that I can just copy the entire lib folder.

Any thoughts and help are highly appreciated!

Best
newMavenUser

Comment: It's easier to convert the project to a maven project by adding a pom.xml file rather than manually installing the jars manually. Anyway the installed jars won't be of any help to a non-maven project.

Comment: Rakesh, Thank you for your comment. How do I install those jars into the Maven repository? as there are so many, is my option to run "mvn deploy" cmd for each of them?

Comment: This comes from the Pom file. You need to provide one with the dependencies needed.

Comment: Ravn, Thanks for the comment, I think my issue is how to install all these jars in the Lib folder into my local repository. these jars are local jars and not available in the central repository.  so I have to install them into my local repository,  Is there an automatic way, or I have manually install them by running the mvn command one by one. Thanks